# PHP session does not work for ionic app in IOS emulator?

Tags: php, ios, angular, xcode, ionic3

I am using php backend controllers with Ionic 3 application.
Ionic 3 login works perfect with back-end controller and creates session and I store user data in the session variable.
When I access another controller via Ionic 3 after login success,It get destroyed.
I need to keep session data until it destroy on logout.

**But the app works completely fine in android.**

**I am using ios simulator(ios 10.3) on Xcode 8.3.3**

Here is my code.

```
 userInfo={} as UserInfo;

  this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'index.php/login/user_login', credentials, options).
  map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
        data => {

          if(data['status']==true && data['data']['login']==true){

            //Store user Info
            this.userInfo.username=data['data']['user_details']['username'];
            this.userInfo.user_type=data['data']['user_details']['user_type'];
            this.userInfo.user_id=data['data']['user_details']['user_id'];

            this.storage.set('user_info',this.userInfo).then(()=>{
              this.gui_permission();
              this.isLoggedIn=true;
              this.loggedUser=this.user.username;
            });

            this.loading.dismiss();

            this.storage.set('user',this.user.username).then(()=>{
              this.isLoggedIn=true;
              this.loggedUser=this.user.username;
            });
```

This is how I check the session data in PHP.

//Checking whether user logged or not

```
public function is_login(){

     $details = $this->session->userdata('username');
     $is_loged_in = $this->session->userdata('loged_in');

     if(!$details || !$is_loged_in) {
         redirect('login');
     }
}
```

Help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: PHP Session won't work on this situation, you will need to use Token based auth process, like as: [JWT](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt)

Comment: But it works on android.

Comment: You are probably using webviews for Android, but UIViewController for iOS (which means that the whole cookie thing (for the php sessions) won't work the usual way. Best way would be to like @HOSSAINAZADSHOHAG said, use some JWT auth or something like that.